# cannot find the "android:layout_width" attribute of TextView in the android official documents?

Tags: android, xml, layout, textview

The official explanations of `TextView` is [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

i tried to find the XML attribute: `android:layout_width` of `TextView`, but i cannot find it. Also, all the `android:layout_xxx` attributes are missing on the web page. does android website forget to put it here? or i miss something on the web page? i know that i can search for the attribute with google. anyhow, the "android:layout_xxx" is a part of `TextView`, and the web page should refer to it on the page of `TextView`. or i would think that "android:layout_xxx" isnt a part of `TextView` XML attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layout_width

Google doesn't forget them, but put them into another place. In the TextView page, there is a link to the xml attributes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's in the `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` documentation. And all the `layout_` attributes are documented in corresponding `LayoutParams` classes.